# Add/edit functions of Emacs Editor

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, emacs23

I need to implement some new functions on an editor. I picked Emacs - although my main programming knowledge is in Java and C - and I want to add some functions and edit some existing functions of Emacs Editor. I looked at the source code of it and I'm a bit lost. I was wondering whether anyone can give me some advice about where to start and whether there are any tutorials that can help?

P.S. One specific question would be how one can start to write a new mode with all new features and behaviour? or how I can disable some basic functions like copy/paste?

Cheers

Comment: You need to tell us what kind of features you want to perofrm. Do you know yet if it needs to be a major-mode, or would a a minor-mode suffice? Are you inventing a new file-format? What's going on here? Are you sure there is not already support?

Comment: If you are a newcomer to Emacs, you might be better asking questions such as 'How do I do X with Emacs ?' rather than 'How do I program Emacs to do X ?' You might be surprised and find that Emacs already does X.

Comment: I appreciate your replies guys. Cheekysoft, I'm working on a whole new file-format and I want to apply certain restrictions on how the file is processed withing Emacs. The copy/paste example or certain functions that prevent certain users to see certain parts of a file and stuff like that. I think I need a major mode and yet I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: "prevent certain users to see certain parts of a file and stuff like that" -- well yeah, it can be done in a major mode, but user can just switch major mode and see everything(you can't restrict, I mean, that's pointless).

Comment: I am removing the security tag from this.  stop asking these non-security questions with a security tag.

Comment: @Arash ok,  what is preventing me from loading up VI and bypassing this restriction or using `fopen()`?  How does this prevent an attacker from gaining access to a restricted resource?  If you can answer that,  then yes this is in fact a security question.   But as it stands,  this is in no way shape or form a security system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tutorials out there specifically geared towards writing a major mode.

- [emacs extension guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20060212105628/http://www.emacs.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/O%27Reilly_Emacs/Writing%20GNU%20Emacs%20Extensions.PDF) [pdf]
- [how to write a major mode...](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html)

Other than that, writing modes in Emacs is just writing Lisp functions.

One thing I will note is that what you're proposing to do here may be pointless; if you implement a permission system as a major mode, a user can simply switch modes to turn it off. That's fine if the point of this permission system is to avoid clobbering edits (in which case I assume your users will cooperate with your aims). If you're expecting your users to be adversarial, then Emacs is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply mate. I was thinking of editing the source code in a way that other modes can not be used, that is only this mode and only in the way I expect the users to interact with the system is possible. Is this not possible at all? - as it's an access control system I aim to prevent users to do certain tasks and that includes malicious users too. Cheers

Comment: @Arash - Technically, yes. I have to ask though; are you familiar with the GPL? Also, how far are you planning to take the enforced permissions? If you need to absolutely guarantee the secrecy of certain parts of a file that you want to send to your users... that may not end well for you. For instance, what if your user uses another text editor to open the file? If you want parts of a file to only be visible to some users, you could do something clever with public or symmetric key crypto, but that's something you should implement as part of the file format rather than the editor.

Comment: The first link is broken. Here is one which works (as of 12/2016): https://ebooks-it.org/1565922611-ebook.htm

Answer (score 3):

**An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp**  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/  or type in emacs:

```
M-: (info "(eintr)Top") RET
```

**Emacs Lisp Manual** http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html  or type in emacs:

```
M-: (info "(elisp)Top") RET
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the manual section on defining major and minor modes:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

It is often beneficial to derive a new mode from an existing one which provides similar basic functionality to what you need.

If there's nothing which matches closely enough, examining the source code for modes which provide some of the same behaviour would be the next best thing.

I note that 'deriving' a mode from `nil` seems to be the common way of creating a completely new major mode. That way you still get all the benefits of the `define-derived-mode` macro.